# How to map a JSON array with RestKit

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I have json string like this format :

```
[{"image":"/0001.jpg","link":"/index.php"},
{"image":"/0001.jpg","link":"/index.php"}]
```

it does not have a key in the top level.

```
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"image" toAttribute:@"image"];
```

mapping like this won't work , it give me the error:

```
restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:81 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
```

How to map this type of json ?

Comment: Is that the proper format for a JSON dictionary, I thought it was formal to add a key to the top level. I'm guessing it's not your json to edit with though, intriguing.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ <- found a json validator, appears that it's a valid format. :O

Comment: I've not found a way to do it. Fortunately, I have control over my server also and modified the server to add the top level key.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:myObject];
```

You should check "[Mapping without KVC](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md#mapping-without-kvc)" section on Restkit Object Mapping Docs.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
[
    { "title": "RestKit Object Mapping Intro",
      "body": "This article details how to use RestKit object mapping...",
      "author": {
          "name": "Blake Watters",
          "email": "blake@restkit.org"
      },
      "publication_date": "7/4/2011"
    }
]
```

And you map that like this:

```
// Our familiar articlesMapping from earlier
RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"body" toAttribute:@"body"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"author" toAttribute:@"author"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"publication_date" toAttribute:@"publicationDate"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:articleMapping];
```

Comment: hmm, looks list the current RK version doesn't have this `-addObjectMapping` method. What can we do now? Any update?

Comment: This answer has 5 years... not developing on iOS now :C

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:

add this response descriptor, use the object inside de array

```
[manager addResponseDescriptor:[ObjectInsideTheArray getResponseDescriptor]];
```

and in the success response

NSArray *response = (NSArray *)[mappingResult **array**]; //instead of firstObject